# Network Card (NIC RTL8111HS) Driver installation 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, kernel, nic

I just installed Ubuntu Server (Bionic Beaver) on a new PC.

It seems like my internet connection does not work at all (pinging Google does not work and the orange LED on the ethernet port lights constantly), so I did some research on Google (via another PC...).

I found out that this could be an incompatible driver version. 
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS comes with **Linux Kernel 4.15** (https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Bionic_Beaver/).
My NIC: **Realtek 8111HS**

As I have absolutely no experience with drivers and that kind of things, I visited some webpages and found the following:

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/r8168-dkms 
  which seems to be an older driver version as it says *"This driver should only be used for devices not yet supported by the
  in-kernel driver r8169."*
- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek?h=v4.15 Indeed, (I think) this shows that Kernel 4.15 comes with the newer 8169 driver version
- https://medium.com/@lgobinath/no-ethernet-connection-in-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18-with-realtek-rtl8111-8168-8411-7ae2779dc9b8 This article is about the same problem (more or less)
- https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/advanced-search/72?Itemid=276 This is the **Realtek Software Download** site, unfortunately, my NIC is not listed there, but only some others like *RTL8111F*, *RTL8111G* and *RTL8111GUS*. However, the software button takes me to this download site:
- https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software So I chose *Unix (Linux)* -> *LINUX driver for kernel up to 4.15* and downloaded the software. What did I get? Driver version **r8168-8.046.00**. Strange, as this version does not appear on the site above. Instead, the launchpad site (link above) shows me several versions of which the latest are **r8168-dkms 8.045.08-2 in amd64 (Proposed)/(Released)**. So I also downloaded the *(Released)* version there by clicking on it -> Downloadable files -> downloading the *.deb* file. I don't think that that's the right file though, because the folder structure is weird: it contains two directories 'control' and 'data'. So I assume this is for Debian only, not for Ubuntu and consequently not for me. 
  So I also downloaded the source file from here:
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/r8168/8.045.08-2 I chose the largest file which is about 1.2MB (fortunately, because the other file I downloaded, the 8.046 file, has about the same size, so I feel confirmed). 
  One thing that I still don't understand is why the included README file lists a ton of NICs: *This is the Linux device driver released for RealTek RTL8168B/8111B, RTL8168C/8111C, RTL8168CP/8111CP, RTL8168D/8111D, RTL8168DP/8111DP, and RTL8168E/8111E Gigabit Ethernet controllers with PCI-Express interface.*, but my **Realtek 8111HS** is not included although the launchpad site again explicitly lists my NIC.

So the steps I would take to resolve my problem are the following:

- Take the 'r8168_8.045.08.orig.tar.bz2' file [from here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/r8168/8.045.08-2), put it onto a USB stick, plug the stick into the Ubuntu PC, copy the file to the root folder (extract) and execute *autorun.sh* with root rights (or basically, do everything as mentioned in the README).

Is that correct? Will everything work after that? Do I still have to patch anything or uninstall the old driver or reload anything? Will it work? Are my assumptions correct?

I know, this question might be a little long, however I think it was more important to be accurate than keeping the answer short and (maybe) forgetting something.

Edit: Just found out that v8.046 is part of Ubuntu Cosmic. 
Also, I configured my network by editing the yaml file in `/etc/netplan` with DHCPv4 [as described here.](https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-static-ip-addresses-on-ubuntu-18-04-beta/)(and with correct indentation!)

The result of `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3`:

```
02:00:0 Ethernet controller [<red>0200</red>]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Onboard Ethernet [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: 8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

The Netplan configuration file (YAML):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp3s0:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
```

Comment: [See this also.](https://www.unixblogger.com/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/)

Comment: You're right, I also came across that. Anyways, did I choose the right driver to install?

Comment: I think so. Are you sure that the ethernet is configured rightly. Check at settings > Network > Wired > Settings (the wheel on the right).

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu Server. Theres no GUI. @Hobbyist

Comment: Of-course try [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html.en)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't have access to the machine now, but I'll add it asap! Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 Thank, I now added the result of the command.

Comment: It appears that the right driver for your device is already installed. May we see: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the indentation is correct. Please try:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
```

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Assuming there are no errors or warnings, reboot and you should be connected.

Reference: `/usr/share/doc/netplan.io/examples/dhcp.yaml`

Comment: Correct. And I had to change the interface name as well. Thanks for your patience!